# jQuery :first-child Not Working As Expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have a form the looks like this:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c6JJ3/)

```
<ul id="services">
<li class="service"><label><input type="checkbox">A single option</label>
</li>
<li class="service"><label><input type="checkbox">Another single option</label>
<ul>
    <li>
    <select>
    </select>
     additional options</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="service"><label>
<select>
</select>
A multiple option</label>
<ul>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox"> with another option </label>
    <select>
    </select>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="service"><label>
<select>
</select>
Another multiple option</label>
<ul>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox"> with another option </label>
    <select>
    </select>
    </li>
    <li>
    <select>
    </select>
     additional options</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

​
and I'm trying to select only the `<label>`s in the first level of `<li>`s with a "service" class by using this:

```
$(".service label:first-child").css("background", "yellow");​
```

but is seems to be recursive, and is selecting the first child of the nested `<ul>`s.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I only select the `<label>`s in the first level of the `<li>`s with a "service" class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".service > label").css("background", "yellow");​
```

[**Fixed DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c6JJ3/2/)

---

`>` is direct child selector.

so `a > b` selector means, select `b` only if it's direct parent is `a`.

[**w3 spec:**](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators)

**8.2. Child combinators**

> A child combinator describes a childhood relationship between two elements. A child combinator is made of the "greater-than sign" (U+003E, >) character and separates two sequences of simple selectors.

---

`:first-child` selector means, select the element which is the first child of it's parent.

[**w3spec:**](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#first-child-pseudo)

**6.6.5.6. :first-child pseudo-class**

> Same as :nth-child(1). The :first-child pseudo-class represents an element that is the first child of some other element.

Answer (score 1):

you need to be explicit that you want the children, from the parent and not all the childs

```
 $(".service > label").css("background", "yellow");​
```

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/justelnegro/c6JJ3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`$("#services>li>label").css("background", "yellow");​`

To get only the direct children you use the `>`.

You can get more info on the selectors here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Your jsfiddle has some issues I think but if you only want to the first level of li's that's all you need to do.

Comment: what the `:` in your selector should do?

Comment: Copy paste problem.. Removed.